# Change the CIDR subnet of GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two GKE clusters with the same CIDR subnet addresses (the clusters are in different gcloud project). I need to connect the VPC with VPC peering but I get an error because the CIDR subnet and I need to change one. I have a lot of pods, secrets, deployemts...etc. Are any way to change the subnet without creating a new cluster and migrating the pods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot, A subnet CIDR range in one peered VPC network cannot overlap with a static route in another peered network. This rule covers both subnet routes and static routes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My doubt is about change the subnet of a GKE cluster, I know I can't peer two VPC with the same CIDR but what I want its create a new subnet to change the GKE cluster and then, delete the old subnet.

Comment: You can't change the subnet for a GKE cluster.  What are you trying to accomplish with VPC peering?